# Restart Visual Studio with admin privileges

Tags: visual-studio

Sometimes I forget to run Visual Studio as Administrator and I run VS normally. 
I know how to run Visual Studio as Administrator. What I am asking is restarting Visual Studio with same project with admin privileges while it is already opened.

Is there an easy way to restart VS with admin privileges?

Comment: You could use the Compatbility Settings for "always run as Administrator". IIRC, those crossed Links and applied to the executeable directly. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to restart with admin privilege. Just close and reopen with admin privilege and select the first solution from the list of recent solutions list.

Comment: Maybe this extension may do the job (haven't tried it) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulMelia.VsRestart001

Comment: I checked. Enabling compatbiltiy settings does seem to be done on the applicaiton, not the link level.

Comment: @StephanBauer He does not want the "Compatibility settings" for all starts, so I guess your idea is it.

Comment: It is really odd that you even need Administive rights. Aside from read rights and maybe the execution level of hte compiled programm, I can not think of any difference. And there are better solutions for those problems, usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of this plug-ins: 
[VS restart plugins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tag%3A%20Restart%20elevated&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance)

Comment: Thanks, This seems perfect for me: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulMelia.VsRestart001

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this:

1. Rightclick on the application. Select Properties.
2. Select Compatability.
3. Check Run the program as Administrator.

Comment: I don't want to run it always with admin privileges. I need admin privileges just for one project.

Comment: ok. create a shortcut of the project. then rightclick on the shortcut -> Select Properties -> Click on the Shortcut tab -> Click Advanced -> Run as administrator